# Massive congratulations to France ON/FOR(?) beating Iceland AT/IN(?) Euro 2016 Quarter-Final

Tags: word-usage

Massive congratulations to France ON/FOR(?) beating Iceland by 5-2 AT/IN(?) Euro 2016 Quarter-Final.

Should "by 5-2" be replaced by "by the score of 5-2"? (and should the word "by" in this question be replaced by "with"??)

Also, is there any need to put "The" before the word "Euro"?

Last question --> should this kind of question be placed on somewhere else (other tags)? If yes, what tag would suit best?

Comment: "Massive" is an unusual modifier for "congratulations".

Answer (score 1):

You will find that different English-speaking countries have different conventions when reporting sporting events. Considering only written media, a typical Monday publication will report tens of matches played over the weekend, and as the readership will be very familiar with the context we see quite terse reporting of statistical data.

In this example

> Sean Davis’ rebound was all the offense the New York Red Bulls II would need as they held the Harrisburg City Islanders at bay the rest of the way for a 1-0 victory on Thursday at Red Bull Arena. With the win, NYRBII moved alongside Louisville City FC atop the Eastern Conference in points with identical 8-1-3 records and 27 points.

you can see

> a 1-0 victory

and

> 8-1-3 records

no need to explain 8 wins, 1 loss, 3 draws.

However to English eyes that looks quite odd; UK newspapers do not use the 8-1-3 convention - and indeed I had at first read that as 8 wins, 1 draw, 3 defeats. We also would not use the phrase "all the offense"

So, I would usually expect not to see "by the score of" in a match report. In fact I would not even expect to see **by**.

> beat Iceland 5-2

would be entirely sufficient. It would be grammatically correct to include **by the score of**, but would be considered cumbersome; the sort of language a non-football enthusiast would use.

I would expect to **in the** if you intend to refer to the specific round in the tournament.

> beat Iceland 5-2 in the Euro 2016 Quarter-final.

You could just refer to the whole tournament, in which case **at** just about works

> beat Iceland 5-2 at Euro 2016

Comment: +1 for the "in the quarter-final" and "at Euro 2016" distinction.